# FTP Connection Error 550

Tags: ftp

I can able see the root directory of the server unable to create folder and files. I am getting FTP error 550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTP error 500 means invalid port, are you sure that you are using the right ports? Normally, it should be 21, sometimes 20... never heard of something else but it should be possible :)

Comment: I am using port no- 21. I can able to connect with server. But i unable to create folder or file. I using anonymous user details.any idea?

Comment: Your FTP server is malconfigured, 550 means "Permission Denied".. an anonymous user normally has absolute no rights.